# vba set x = range(a) ;method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed

Tags: vba, range, global

The following snippet fails on `Set x = Range("services" & sheetname)` with error message `method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed`.
Can anyone please help?

```
Sub add_Click()
    Dim sheetname As String
    Dim x As Range
    sheetname = selectSheetName(form1.age.value)
    Sheets(sheetname).activate
    Set x = Range("services" & sheetname) '<-- error here
end sub
Function selectSheetName(byval age as integer)
    If (age > 20 And age < 36) Then
        selectSheetName = "21-35"
    End If
    If (age > 35 And age < 61) Then
        selectSheetName = "36-60"
    End If
    If (age > 60 And age < 81) Then
        selectSheetName = "61-80"
    End If
End Function`
```

there is are 3 sheets named: "21-35"; "36-60"; "61-80".

In each sheet there is a range named "services" & sheet.

For example in sheet "21-35" the range is "services21-35".

Comment: It would be helpful to know what precisely you're trying to do.

Comment: Imagining that `services` + something is the name of a named range, we cannot answer your question without knowing: 1) what is the value you assign to `age`; 2) what is the content (or at least the output) of the function `selectSheetName()`; 3) if you really have a range with that name you try to use for assigning `x`.

Comment: @MatteoNNZ I've added some more information

Comment: Could you please add the line `MsgBox form1.age.value` just before the line `sheetname = selectSheetName(form1.age.value)` and tell us what you see in the message dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`services21-35` is not a valid range name: I can't create that name because it contains a `-`

Comment: Thanks man, I've checked  the range names and found that there We're no ranges because  excel doesn't accept ranges with"-". I named the range with underscore between the numbers and it worked.